# How to run the unit test I am getting 415 error , but passing the json in correct format?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

```
@Test
public void testAuthenticationForSubmitModelingRequest() {

    String url = "http://localhost:9081/prop/submitModellingRequest";
    String name = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    String authString = name + ":" + password;
    byte[] authStringEnc =  Base64.getEncoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
    String input = "{\"modelingVersionID\":\"1007\",\n" + 
            "\"modelingRequestID\":\"75891\",\n" + 
            "\"cycleId\":\"20033\",\n" + 
            " \"imtId\":\"225\",\n" + 
            " \"submarketID\":\"0\",\n" + 
            "\"brandSubSubGroupID\":\"11\",\n" + 
            "\"modelStatus\":null,\n" + 
            "\"modelingTechStatus\":null,\n" + 
            "\"requestType\":null,\n" + 
            "\"targetType\":\"0\",\n" + 
            "\"targetTypeName\":null,\n" + 
            "\"serverId\":\"1\"}";
    String authStringEnc1 = new String(authStringEnc);
    System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
    Client restClient = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
    ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json").header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc1)
            .post(ClientResponse.class,input);
    if (resp.getStatus() != 201) {
        System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
    }
    String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("response: " + output);

}
```

Getting 415 error when trying to  run the unit test even though passing the json in correct format..trying to call post method on my rest api please help

Comment: You have to set the content type to application/json

Comment: it is set to application/json, still getting the error

Comment: in the provided code, it's visible that you set "Accept", not "Content-Type"

Comment: Call `type("application/json")`.

Comment: thanks it is working after calling type("application/json")